# Can I create a custom UIView from a .xib and then use that view for my UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I need to refactor my UI where I had a UIButton with two labels placed on top of it and constraints set in order to display it properly.

What I have done is created a custom UIView that looks exactly like my previous button but now with the labels contained within the view and constraints inside the .xib instead of in the storyboard where they were placed.

I want this new view to be used as the buttons view; is this possible?
If not, is the way to make my custom view "like" a button is to used touchesBegan/touchesEnded? How do I handle the touchDown highlight of the system UIButton?

Thanks!

Comment: How were you using the "UIButton with two labels placed on top" before? As a Button, or by adding your own touch handling?

Comment: As a button, it just had two uilabels placed on top of it in my storyboard

Comment: Why not just add the custom UIView as button subview?